# Set Tor Browser Bundle to use English Language for Google Search from the search bar

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, google

I use Tor Browser Bundle, and I want to use Google Search instead of Startpage:

[image]

But one problem is that Google constantly shifts the language depending on your exit node IP. I want to fix that by setting `?hl=en`, i.e. the search URL should be:

```
https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%s
```

I know how to edit search engines in Chrome, but in Tor Browser Bundle I couldn't find a way to specify a custom search engine with %s as a placeholder, nor did I find a way to edit the current search engines.

I want to set Google to always use English (`?hl=en` does that), how can I do that in Tor Browser Bundle?

Answer (score 2):

I have also had this issue, but have been able to resolve it by installing a "Google US" Search Engine. You can do this by going to http://mycroftproject.com/google-search-plugins.html and choosing the third option "Google"

[image: Mycroft Project]

You should then see the option to add the Search Engine. You also have the option to set it as the default.

[image: Add Search Engine]

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Well,if you enable cookies,you can cilck http://www.google.com/ncr, next time google will not shift the language.If not,it seems that there is no way to stop google`s auto shifting.